# JQuery .click function not working for contained <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have the following function that is supposed to trigger anytime one of the numbers in my pagination is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("div.pagination a").click(function(event) {
        alert("Click");
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("input[name='order']").val(order);
        $("#form_session").attr('action', url).submit();
    });
</script>
```

The pagination looks like this:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="results.php?page=1&agruments...">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="results.php?page=2&arguments...">2</a></li>
    ...etc
  </ul>
</div>
```

For some reason, the function is never firing. I even put in a very obvious alert to confirm that it's hearing the click, but I'm not even seeing this.

So what is it that I'm doing wrong Everything seems correct to me...

Comment: Chances are the DOM isn't ready when your code runs. Put it in a DOM ready event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` Something like below,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("div.pagination li").click(function(event) {
        alert("Click");
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("input[name='order']").val(order);
        $("#form_session").attr('action', url).submit();
    });

 });
```

If the `li` is dynamically generated then you should use `.on` (for jQuery 1.7) or `.live/.delegate` (older jQuery).

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', 'div.pagination li', function(event) {
        alert("Click");
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("input[name='order']").val(order);
        $("#form_session").attr('action', url).submit();
    });

 });
```

**Note:** Replace `$(document).on('click', 'div.pagination li', function(event) {` with `$('div.pagination').on('click', 'li', function(event) {` if `div.pagination` exist on load.

Comment: Where does the .on go? Yes the <li> are generated dynamically

Comment: @Jon Updated with .on. When I said dynamic, it means the `li` are inserted into the `ui` or the whole `ul` is generated at runtime using javascript.

Comment: Got it! The function is triggering now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Put it in a `document.ready`

```
$(function(){ 
    $("div.pagination a").click(function(event) {
            alert("Click");
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $("input[name='order']").val(order);
            $("#form_session").attr('action', url).submit();
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.pagination li a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Click");
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        $("input[name='order']").val(order);
        // Where is order coming from?
        $("#form_session").attr('action', url).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

You missed the `a` in your selector. Make sure the DOM is ready `$(document).ready`. And where is the order variable coming from? Is `order` defined?

Comment: Still not working :/ I also tried just doing "div.pagination a" in the selector...no luck.

Comment: @Jon Yeah you are referencing a variable `order` here: `$("input[name='order']").val(order);`. Where is that coming from?

Comment: How'bout div.pagination ul li, or div.pagination ul li a? I'm pretty sure you can't skip the ul.

Comment: This works, but now the links don't work...it's not sending me to the next page.

Comment: Then remove `event.preventDefault();`.